# Flutter add Text styling to a custom class

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to add text styling to the Score class in this widget. I have another widget that uses this widget to generate a circle with a number in it.

```
Center(
     child: Container(
       width: 100.0,
       height: 100.0,
       decoration: BoxDecoration(
         color: Colors.grey[600],
         shape: BoxShape.circle,
       ),
       child: Score(score: 'score',
```

Comment: Can you please provide more info, as you have not used any text styling in the code, are you looking for the boxDecoration code to be in the class

Comment: I have another stateful widget that is pulling in this shape and ideally the text styling from this container. The text is in that other widget. I was hoping I could put the styling in this widget.
I have not put text styling in this code because I cannot figure out how to do the styling without the text from the other widget.

Answer (score 0):

// Are you looking for something like this

```
class CenterClass extends StatelessWidget {
  const CenterClass({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        width: 100.0,
        height: 100.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey[600],
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ));
  }
}
```

YOu can achieve same via Widgets

```
Widget circleContainer() {
    return Container(
        width: 100.0,
        height: 50.0,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.grey[600],
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you wanted to like A BALL that show the score of ball like below image
[image]

If I Am Right then code is below

```
Container(
  width: 27,
  height: 27,
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(1),
    child: Container(
      child: Center(
        child: Text(
          '4',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.white,
              fontWeight:
                  FontWeight.bold,
              fontSize: 11,
              fontFamily: 'Tahoma',
              ),
            ),
          ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        shape: BoxShape.circle,
        color: Color(0xffffc11c), // inner circle color
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```